# Java Play2 Spring Testing - Test Context Dependency Injection?

Tags: java, unit-testing, playframework

Say I have a play Global file...

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

    private ApplicationContext ctx;

    @Override
    public void onStart(Application app) {
        ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context/components.xml");
    }

    @Override
    public <A> A getControllerInstance(Class<A> clazz) {
        return ctx.getBean(clazz);
    }
}
```

And I have a test like this...

```
@Test
public void itShouldFailOnMissingFields() throws Exception {
    running(fakeApplication(), () -> {
                Map<String, String> body = new HashMap<String, String>();
                body.put("email", "jason@goodwin.com");
                body.put("password", "ro");
                FakeRequest request = new FakeRequest(POST, "/v1/profile")
                        .withFormUrlEncodedBody(body);
                Result result = route(request);
                assertEquals(status(result), 400);
            }
    );
}
```

How can I get test dependencies injected into a controller? Is there some other way I should be testing this?

Comment: You should be able to create your controller manually with the test dependencies (ex `new MyController(new TestDep())` and then call the right method), or using [Play.isTest](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/java/play/Play.html#isTest()) to check if you are running in test mode and then initialize a different context

Answer (score 0):

There was an answer on google groups

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/MpjMQhEC2C4